# Can't import SPM Objective-C classes to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I've created SPM package from a XCFramework to expose legacy Objective-C code (only objc, it's not a mixed package) to my project,
I have no trouble importing the framework's classes on Objective-C, but when trying to access them from Swift I get `Cannot find type 'MyClass' in scope`.
I've added `#import <MyPackage/MyPackage.h>` to my bridging header.

My `Package.swift`:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
        ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MyPackage",
            path: "MyPackage.xcframework"
        ),
    ]
)
```

My `module.modulemap`:

```
framework module MyPackage {
    umbrella header "MyPackage.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Did you export the interface? Also, does your Framework's Umbrella Header (`<MyPackage/MyPackage.h>`) `import` the Objective-C class' header?

Comment: What do you mean by export the interface? and yes, the umbrella does import every class in the framework.

Comment: I meant marking it with `OBJC_EXPORT` like: `OBJC_EXPORT @interface ClassName: NSObject...` Also it's really weird it'd work from Objective-C but not Swift, so without really seeing what's going on, this will be hard to debug.

Comment: My classes interfaces looks something like: ```__attribute__((swift_name("SwiftBase")))
@interface ObjcBase : NSObject
- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable));
+ (instancetype)new __attribute__((unavailable));
+ (void)initialize __attribute__((objc_requires_super));
@end;```

Comment: Adding `OBJC_EXPORT` did not helped still `Cannot find type in scope`